# Override Windows remote desktop settings

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, user-interface

There are some settings in Windows 2012 Server R2 responsible for windows animation (Advanced System Settings -> Performance). I prefer to set here "Adjust for best performance" in order to disable all the animations, but remote desktop client (mstsc) has its own settings for that (on "Experience" tab) allowing an user to override settings made locally.

Is there some way to ignore mstsc settings forcedly and always apply local settings? I am seeking for a solution that could be applied on server side, not on client side.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791756(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @Appleoddity: If I understood right, these policies have to be applied on mstsc client side, not on server side. Haven't they?